# Get column names as values in a new column in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I have sample data with following columns;

```
total_container_cnt | forty_ft_container_cnt | twenty_ft_container_cnt | fifty_three_ft_container_cnt

3                   |      NULL              |    3                    |   NULL
2                   |       2                |      NULL               |   NULL
```

The goal is to get following output;

**Expected output**

```
total_container_cnt | forty_ft_container_cnt | twenty_ft_container_cnt | fifty_three_ft_container_cnt | NEW_COLUMN

3                   |      NULL              |    3                    |   NULL      | 3*twenty_ft_container_cnt
2                   |       2                |      NULL               |   NULL      | 2* forty_ft_container_cnt
```

Here is my attempt at this ,

```
select temp.*,
       case when forty_ft_container_cnt is not null then concat('total_container_cnt','*','forty_ft_container_cnt)
       when twenty_ft_container_cnt is not null then concat('total_container_cnt','*','twenty_ft_container_cnt')
       when fifty_three_ft_container_cnt is not null then concat('total_container_cnt','*','fifty_three_ft_container_cnt)
 end as new_column

from temp
```

This approach works but involve multiple `case when` statements. Is it possible to get some help here to have a simpler/shorter solution? thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to achieve what you want without using a CASE statement per column. You could possibly generate the SQL statement dynamically and then execute it - but probably only worth the effort if the list of columns is going to change frequently. If you just don't want to have to type the code for each column then it's easier enough to build the strings in e.g. Excel using CONCAT and then paste them back into your SQL

Answer (score 0):

You need [UNPIVOT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/unpivot). In the example below, an ID column was added for the join.

```
create or replace temporary table t0(
    id integer,
    total_container_cnt integer,
    forty_ft_container_cnt integer,
    twenty_ft_container_cnt integer,
    fifty_three_ft_container_cnt integer
) as
select * from values
    (101, 3, NULL, 3, NULL),
    (102, 2, 2, NULL, NULL);

with t1 as (
    select * from t0
    unpivot (
            count for container in (forty_ft_container_cnt, twenty_ft_container_cnt, fifty_three_ft_container_cnt)
        )
)
select
    t0.*,
    t1.count || '*' || container as new_column
from t0
join t1
on t0.id = t1.id
    and t1.count > 0;
```

| ID | TOTAL_CONTAINER_CNT | FORTY_FT_CONTAINER_CNT | TWENTY_FT_CONTAINER_CNT | FIFTY_THREE_FT_CONTAINER_CNT | NEW_COLUMN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 3 | null | 3 | null | 3*TWENTY_FT_CONTAINER_CNT |
| 102 | 2 | 2 | null | null | 2*FORTY_FT_CONTAINER_CNT |